# How to filter out rows in Table based on the row values?

Tags: python, numpy, data-science

I'm quite a beginner with python and have a very basic question.
So here, I have created a table like below.

```
A = make_array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g")
B = make_array("No", "10%", "5%", "No", "15%", "21%", "3%")
test = Table().with_columns("A", A, "B", B)
```

I want to filter out the rows that contain "No" and leave only those with integer percentage values. I have tried using where function, but didn't work.

```
test_new = test.where("B" != "No")
```

Could anyone guide me through how I could do it?
As an end goal, I want to have a table with only b,c,e,f,g.

Edit: I'm using Numpy library and datascience pacakge.

Comment: Python has no native `Table` type — what library are you using?

Comment: I'm using the Numpy library and datascience package. Would it help?

Comment: Well, it'll help you get better answers as well help others understand your question because it provides context. I've add them as tags to get things headed in the right direction.

Comment: thank you so much! I edited my post accourdingly.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use `pandas` for that. You could do something like,

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a df with some example data
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"], "B": ["No", "10/%", "5/%", "No", "15/%", "21/%", "3/%"]})

# Only select rows for which column B is not "No". 
df['A'][~df['B'].str.contains("No")]
```

Note that here I used `contains()`, so if the cell contains the substring "No", it will also be selected. If you would like an exact comparison, you could do something like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"], "B": ["No", "10/%", "5/%", "No", "Non", "21/%", "3/%"]})

df['A'][~(df['B'] ==  "No")]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment! I could have written it more clearly, I'm using NumPy library and datascience package. Your method does not seem to work under these conditions, probably because yours is a dataframe and mine is a table. I'm wondering if there is any way to do the same with numpy and datascience, or must I use panda?

Comment: Is this the package you using:  https://pypi.org/project/datascience/?